# Uninstall latest kernel using yum

Tags: yum, linux-kernel, centos-7

The latest kernel `kernel-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64` panics at boot on my CentOS 7 box due to a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1206529).

Since this kernel is the default in GRUB, if I forget to manually change the kernel selection at boot, my machine will crash.

Two questions:

- How can I remove this latest kernel from my system?
- How can I prevent it from being installed in the next `yum update`?

Comment: FYI for others on centos-7: i had something similar where I couldn't boot to the most recent kernel. so i had to uninstall kernel 3.10.0-514 (the working kernel was 3.10.0-327). this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I remove this latest kernel from my system?

I was apparently specifying the version incorrectly. This works:

```
$ sudo yum remove kernel-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7
```

> How can I prevent it from being installed in the next `yum update`?

To do so manually, use the `--exclude` option, like so:

```
$ sudo yum update --exclude=kernel
```

Comment: Also in `/etc/yum.conf` add to `[main]` section `exclude=kernel*`